# Sweat Alert 2 text area not resizing width dynamically

Tags: javascript, user-interface, resize, textarea, sweetalert

I've created a sweet alert text box for myself, it uses 'textarea' as its input property. This means the text box can be dragged to resize its size. Its the exact same code as the example found on https://sweetalert2.github.io/ but unlike the example on the website my one doesn't resize its width dynamically. You can test this out yourself in the snippet, the height resizes fine but not the width. Considering I copied this verbatim from the their own website I'm at a loss as to why its not working. Any insight would be great, perhaps im missing something here.

```js
swal({
    input: 'textarea',
  title: 'Message',
  inputPlaceholder: 'Type your message here...',
  inputAttributes: {
    'aria-label': 'Type your message here'
  },
  showCancelButton: true
    },
    function(){
      location.href= "http://example.com";
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/sweetalert2@6.6.0(sweetalert2.min.js+sweetalert2.js)"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/sweetalert2@6.6.0(sweetalert2.min.css+sweetalert2.css)">
```